# Google maps Custom streetview now ask for zoom level 0 on API Javascript 3.26. Is this a bug?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have been using custom streetview on google maps since V3.22 and I wanted explore the new API 3.26 but something is not ok in this version.

When I try to load my old custom streetview images, the API 3.26 now ask for a zoom level 0. This was not happening before, you can test it in this jsfiddle

```
function initPano() {  

// Set up Street View and initially set it visible. Register the
  // custom panorama provider function. Set the StreetView to display
  // the custom panorama 'reception' which we check for below.
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('map'), {
      pano: 'reception',
      visible: true,
      panoProvider: getCustomPanorama
  });
}

// Return a pano image given the panoID.
function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
  // Note: robust custom panorama methods would require tiled pano data.
  // Here we're just using a single tile, set to the tile size and equal
  // to the pano "world" size.
  console.log(zoom);
  return 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/saulbpano/panoramas/8/341/' +  
         zoom + '/' + tileX + '/' + tileY + '.jpg';
}

// Construct the appropriate StreetViewPanoramaData given
// the passed pano IDs.
function getCustomPanorama(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
  if (pano === 'reception') {
    return {
      location: {
        pano: 'reception',
        description: 'Google Sydney - Reception'
      },
      links: [],
      // The text for the copyright control.
      copyright: 'Imagery (c) 2010 Google',
      // The definition of the tiles for this panorama.
      tiles: {
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256,256),
        worldSize: new google.maps.Size(4096, 2048),
        // The heading in degrees at the origin of the panorama
        // tile set.
        //centerHeading: 105,
        getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
      }
    };
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SaulBurgos/gkasqm0x/2/

Initially the jsfiddle is loading my custom streetview because I am loading the version 3.22. Now please change to the version 3.23, 3.24, 3.25 and you will see that is ok.

But if you load the version 3.26 will not load. Any idea why is this happening ? Maybe a bug ?

I Have read the documentation but I could not find what can be the problem.

All my custom streetview images are created with level zoom folders 1,2,3,4,etc. Never 0 and I always use images with the dimensions 4096x2048

I found this script time ago on PHP to create my custom streetview images.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/jamestomasino/5360150)

Comment: There is a new StreetView rendering engine in v3.26.  See [Issue 7452: StreetViewCoverageLayer() has stopped showing PhotoSphere and Maps for Business points](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7452) for history.

Comment: I have read all the topic,  I saw similar cases but nobody is talking about the zoom level 0.  Well My only concern is : Is this a bug ? or it will be the final implementation in the 3.26 ?  Because in this moment I do not know what to do .. Update my code ? or wait to see if this is a bug ?   There is not nothing documented about if this is the final behaviour

Comment: My guess is it is not a "bug", merely a change due to the implementation.  But if it is causing you issues, you should either open a new issue in the issue tracker or make a comment on that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this issue by providing a 1x1 pixel spacer gif when the zoom level is zero / 0. Update the getTileUrl function as below.

Download spacer from http://spacergif.org/

```
  getTileUrl: function (pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
                if (zoom === 0)
                    return 'SOME_PATH/spacer.gif';

                return 'SOME_PATH' + '/' + zoom  + '/' + tileX + '/' + tileY + '.jpg';
            }
```

Comment: Woow is working....incredible. I do not know why but is working. Could you explain me a little bit why ?

Comment: Thanks for accepting as answer... Well it seems that their new code logic by defaults need a zero zoom image, if you don't provide it, the code just stops moving ahead...Providing a spacer.gif fills this gap. Everyone is happy now!